# How to proxy 127.0.0.1:8000/wordpress/ to www.domain.com/ in Nginx and Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

How to proxy 127.0.0.1:8000/wordpress/ to www.domain.com/  in Nginx and Wordpress?

And make sure the site resouce path and  redirection is correct.

And for example , when the user opening www.domain.com, it will show the result of 127.0.0.1:8000/wordpress that runing in the server.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/nginx/sites-available/

```
 server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /var/www/example.com/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name example.com;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 server {
        listen 8000;
        server_name localhost;

        location /wordpress {
            proxy_pass http://www.example.com;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

}
```